# developing SQL 2005 application using SQL 2008 server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am developing an application for one of my customer who has SQL 2005 but I have SQL 2008 on my system. Can I develop my application using SQL 2008 and then ported it simply to SQL 2005? I will use EF and C# for my application and the SQL DB has database (no code).

Answer (score 2):

Just install SQL Server 2005 express and use that

At some point, developing an backward compatible **app** will come back to bite you because there are differences in data types, [deprecated features, discontinued features, and behaviour changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532%28SQL.100%29.aspx). The list is too long to try and remember for development

Comment: +1. Why do people fight for not just doing the most sensible thing. Install a 2005 instance.

Comment: This is the obvious solution, but my question is if there is any better way to do this?

Comment: @user654019: No. Never develop for an older version. It'd be acceptable, mostly, to work on SS2005 for SS2008 but never the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

But there are some differences between SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 databases. You should read up on those to make sure your database is compatible with SQL Server 2005.
For example some datatypes only exists in the one version and not the other and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate more? What should I do in EF and in database creation? Where can I find information about the datatypes which is not supported in 2005 and so on?

Comment: It's too much information to gather without knowing the specifics of your application. As gbn mentioned you are better off installing a sql 2005 express instead of spending valuable time googling around for differences between sql 2005 and 2008