# SQL Server 2008 T-SQL features do not respect compatibility levels

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have inadvertently used a couple of the SQL Server 2008 T-SQL features in a script containing a function which will be deployed to numerous customer databases, some of which will be SQL 2005.

An example of an offending statement:

```
create function dbo.fnThisWontWorkOnSQL2005
    ()
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @intCounter int = 2
    return @intCounter
end

select dbo.fnThisWontWorkOnSQL2005()
```

On a SQL2008 instance this will return 2.

On a SQL2005 instance this advises "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable."

However, on a SQL 2005 database set by compatibility level running on a SQL2008 R2 instance the code runs happily and returns 2.

My issue arises as I am developing on a SQL2008R2 instance and I had assumed that setting the compatibility level of the target database to SQL Server 2005 would flag up any invalid T-SQL though this does NOT happen, or at least I can find nothing to prevent it happening.

Is anyone aware of a way to prevent this happening? I have searched variously but cannot find a way and it feels like a bug to me or do I always need to develop on the lowest SQL version I will be deploying to?

Comment: FYI: "delighters" isn't the correct word: I guessed you mean new "features"

Comment: I only found this name from Microsoft article at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270%28SQL.100%29.aspx where this is what they call them 

Transact-SQL Delighters

Transact-SQL delighters are small enhancements that, for the most part, help make the programming experience more convenient. This section covers the following Transact-SQL delighters: declare and initialize variables, compound assignment operators, table value constructor support through the VALUES clause, and the enhanced CONVERT function

Comment: Written by a non-native English speaker (Itzik is Israeli). I'll rephrase: the word has subtle overtones unsuitable for a public forum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct.

Compatibility level does not mean "run exactly like an older version"
It means "break less often while I fix the code".

Never assume: check. This is what [ALTER DATABASE says on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) says (my bold):

> Compatibility level provides only **partial** backward compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server. Use compatibility level as an **interim** migration aid to work around version differences in the behaviors that are controlled by the relevant compatibility-level setting. If existing SQL Server applications are affected by behavioral differences in SQL Server 2008, **convert the application** to work properly

If you target SQL Server 2005, develop on SQL Server 2005. See [developing SQL 2005 application using SQL 2008 server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7803978/27535) too

Comment: I get that but this is surely the reverse in that it's providing forward compatibility in that a SQL2005 db is running a piece of code which it shouldn't recognise.

It's also odd from Microsoft's perspective. They don't want me to stay on SQL2000 until every last database is converted to the latest and greatest.

Comment: When you take a SQL Server 2005 database to a later version, it upgrades the database. It is no longer a SQL Server 2005 database. Try to restore or attach it back onto a SQL Server 2005 server: it will fail. The same applies to service packs and some hotfixes, not just releases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857924/restore-sql-2008-db-r2-to-sql2008-no-r2/6857958#6857958

Comment: That makes sense. I need to be more careful what I'm writing and script into lowest version number at the earliest point possible. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

> However, on a SQL 2005 database set by compatibility level running on
>   a SQL2008 R2 instance the code runs happily and returns 2.

Changing to compatibility level 90 does not change your database to a SQL Server 2005 database, it is still a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Compatibility level is not there to prevent you from doing things in SQL Server 2008, it is there to make the functions that was in SQL Server 2005 behave the same way in SQL Server 2008 as they did before.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this question is already answered to death, but further kill it:

The Compatibility Level functionality functionality is designed to help ensure that a SQL Server 2005 application can work with minimal or no changes on a SQL Server 2008 instance (or between any 2 versions basically). Its only purpose is to deal with **changes** in **syntax**, where existing code would probably work incorrectly under 2008 (or whatever later version you're dealing with).

There's a huge list of things that are perfectly usable in 2005 and 2008 databases even when set to 80 (SQL Server 2000) compatibility level:
 - MERGE statements
 - CTEs
 - Default Values for declared parameters
 - New Data Types (eg NVarChar(Max))
 - the list goes on and on.

I am embarrassed to say that the main system I work with is still running in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode, even though we're now on SQL Server 2008 R2; We're using lots and lots of the newer features, we just never got around to fixing all our table hints. The compatibility level was pretty much created for lazy people like me :) (or rather, to reduce the friction on upgrades to help sell more units of newer versions and reduce the necessary support window on older versions of sql servers - good goals in their own right).