# How to check SQL Server 2008 script will work properly on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there a way (a tool) to check that a SQL Server 2008 script will run on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Install a SQL Server 2005 instance on your machine (or a server in your network) and run them there?

Answer (score 0):

Open up SQL Management studio, rt mouse click on the database name, select properties, select option, set compatability level. Test. A far as is known, when the compatabailty level is set to a (lower) level, functionality is disabled and errors raised entirely in line with the selected level. MS are a bit relctant to comit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510680.aspx but in practice I've not found any issues. You can of course install an instance of the 2005 build and bulk insert for a really thorough check.

Comment: That won't work, because it won't prevent you from using 2008 specific features. It just makes sure that code that worked a certain way on 2005 continues to work the same way in 2008 if 2008 behaves differently. Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877582/sql-server-2008-t-sql-features-do-not-respect-compatibility-levels

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[SQL Fiddle for SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3)**

At the **left top** you can `select` the **RDMS**

Comment: Though a great tool, sqlfiddle doesn't have an option for SQL Server 2005

Comment: Yep, I didn't find this option